# Find the first derivative of the following z function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find the first derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$.

$z = r_L/f_{x}^{'} - r_D/f_{y}^{'} - t(g_{x}^{''}-g_{y}^{''}) * f(x, y)$

where
$f_{x}^{'}$ is the first derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, $g_{x}^{''}$ is the second derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$ and so on.

My first attempt was

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = r_L/f_{x}^{''} - t(g_{x}^{'''}*f(x,y)+g_{x}^{''}*f_{x}^{'})$

Is this correct? I'm mainly in doubt with the first term of the RHS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $r_L$ constant wrt $x$?

Comment: @abs Yes! As well $r_D$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$z = \frac{r_L}{f_{x}^{'}} - \frac{r_D}{f_{y}^{'}} - t(g_{x}^{''}-g_{y}^{''})f(x, y)$$

The second term, as you have written, is correct.

For the first term, use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{r_L}{f_{x}^{'}}\bigg) = r_L \cdot\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{x}^{'}}\bigg(\frac{1}{f_{x}^{'}}\bigg)\bigg) \frac{\partial f_{x}^{'}}{\partial x} = r_L\cdot \bigg( \frac{-1}{f_{x}^{'2}} \bigg) f_{x}^{''}$$

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.